# Is there a simple physical example for the fact 'Changing electric field produces Magnetic field '?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, maxwell-equations, magnetostatics

For Changing magnetic field we have the simple Faraday's Experiment. Similarly for Changing electric field is there a simple experiment where we could see what is happenening.

I searched the internet it showed electric motors. But is there any a simple physical example?

Comment: In the $LC$ countour in the capacitor there is a changing electric field $E$ between the plates and in the coil there would be corresponding change of magnetic field. But maybe it is in some sense indirect influence

Comment: Would you accept "light" as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a charging capacitor. The magnetic field produced inside the capacitor can be found through the displacement current term on Ampere's Law, since the electric field through the capacitor is changing.

In fact, consider an infinitely long wire with a small gap cut in the middle of width much less than the radius of the wire, such that it forms a capacitor. It can be shown that the magnetic field in the gap due to the displacement current is approximately the same as the magnetic field in the wire due to the current.

Comment: This answer is theoretical. The OP asked for an experiment.

Comment: I think this is what happens in the Hertz experiment which produces Electromagnetic wave

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a correspondingly *simple* convincing demonstration.  
However, at RF frequencies the magnetization in a ferrite ring will respond to the changing electric flux threading the ring. This changing magnetization should be readily picked up with a coil wound on the ring. In principle, it should also be possible to pick this up more directly with a suitably sensitive high-frequency magnetometer (Hall-probe, GMR-probe). 
Ferrite antennas as commonly used in AM receivers (~1 MHz), but these work on a different principle.  They are always in the form of a rod and respond to the magnetic field along the length of the rod.  The resulting changing magnetic flux induces a voltage in a coil wound on the rod.
 I have never seen a *ferrite ring* antenna and can find no references to one.  But I am tempted to retire to my ham radio shack and see if I can make one.

Answer (score 1):

I remember about reading a research paper which was written in 1985.There they measured the induced magnetic field between the capacitor using a device called "SQUID".Well they tried to experimentally verify Maxwell's contribution in Ampere's Law.You can check there.
Here's the link ,
https://pages.uncc.edu/nesmelova-lab/wp-content/uploads/sites/138/2012/11/PhysRevLett.55.59.pdf

But since we as high school student or undergrad student never did such a experiment I am almost sure there is no simple experminet.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to Ampère's circuital law
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \mathbf{J} + \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}} {\partial t} ~.$$
Written in this way this law *suggests* that the second term on the right is a current contribution and source of magnetic field. A clearer way to write the equation is perhaps
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}} {\partial t}= \mu_0 \mathbf{J} ~.$$

The displacement term is required for consistency with charge-current conservation. It is required when $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} \neq 0$, as it is always true that $\nabla \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{B} =0$. So if the divergency of the current is non-zero and charge builds up, the effect of the current cannot be described by $\mathbf{B}$ alone and a time derivative of $\mathbf{E}$ also occurs.

Now that the concepts are clear the answer to your question of experimental demonstration is easy. It just requires that besides a magnetic field also a time derivative of $\mathbf{E}$ is observed, for example when charging a capacitor. However, this already follows from the time derivative of the charge on the capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

Connect a battery to the ends of a wire of a solenoid. Because of the potential difference between two end points this will create an electric field thus current. So this way, you can create a uniform magnetic field in the center of a long solenoid. Magnetic field B in the coil will obey the following

$$B =\mu n I$$

where n is the number of turns per unit length. Change the voltage difference, you will see a change in the magnetic field.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked

Comment: That change is due to the change in current, not due to the changing electric field in the wire. The electric field in the wire changes only briefly and then is constant again. OP is asking about magnetic fields from the displacement current term in Ampere's law.